# How to Generate a list of Most Commented post?

Tags: php, loop, database, wpdb

I'm trying to call a list of most commented post. But the call to the DB returns always the same post (the first one in the loop)

This is my code in functions.php

```
function lugaresincreibles_most_commented() {
    global $wpdb;
    $pop = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status='publish' ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 3");
    foreach($pop as $post) :
        get_template_part( 'content', 'featured' );
    endforeach;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `WP_Query()` or `get_posts()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary issue with your function is "get_template_part" internally use global $post variable to display the post fields. However, your $post variable is filled for this function only. I would suggest to read this handy article [Displaying Posts Using a Custom Select Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query)

Now, specifically in your case

```
function lugaresincreibles_most_commented() {
    global $wpdb, $post; // make $post a global variable
    $pop = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status='publish' ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 3");
    foreach($pop as $post) :
        setup_postdata( $post ); // set the post data.
        get_template_part( 'content', 'featured' );
    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @M-R it works like a charm. I'll check the Displaying Post article.